# Vue 3 router link inside a clickable table row

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-router4

Simple question. I have a router link inside a clickable table row. when I click the router link it triggers the `@click` event instead of triggering the `router-link`.

How can I fix this?

```html
<tr v-for="(blabla, index) in data" @click="goToIssue(blabla.id)">
  <td>{{ blabla.id }}</td>
  <td>{{ blabla.username }}</td>
  <td>{{ blabla.name }}</td>
  <td>
    <router-link 
      :to="'/project' + blabla.project.id"
    >
      Details
    </router-link>                     
  </td>                    
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

To stop the `click`-event from bubbling to the parent, use a custom `<router-link>` that uses the `stop` event modifier on the underlying link's `@click`:

1. Apply the [`custom` prop](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#custom) on the `<router-link>`.
2. In the `<router-link>`'s default slot, add an `<a>` with its `href` bound to the slot's `href` prop.
3. Also add a `click`-event handler that calls the slot's `navigate` prop (a function that navigates to `<router-link>`'s `to` prop). Also apply the [`.stop` event modifier](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#event-modifiers) to the `click`-event listener to stop the event from propagating to the parent elements.

```html
<router-link :to="'/project/' + blabla.project.id"
             custom 1️⃣
             v-slot="{ navigate, href }">
  <a :href="href" 2️⃣
     @click.stop="navigate" 3️⃣
  >
    Details
  </a>
</router-link>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-stop-event-bubble?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyTable.vue)